# Perl NULL terminated string

Tags: perl

I am using [Net::SMPP](http://search.cpan.org/~sampo/Net-SMPP-1.19/SMPP.pm) package to handle SMPP protocol.
One of the protocol parameters should be NULL terminated string.
When I send it I do :

```
my $receipted_message_id = '111111'."\0";
```

When I receive it I strip last character.

Is any better way to work with "C String" in Perl ?

Comment: This seems like a perfectly good solution, not very complex, and Perlish in its approach.  Is there some reason you think there should be a different solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could trim the terminating null with a simple substitution:

```
$receipted_message_id =~ s/\0$//;
```

...or simply chop() the last character:

```
chop $receipted_message_id;
```

Answer (score 8):

You might want to look into pack and unpack (perldoc -f pack), specifically:

```
Z  A null-terminated (ASCIZ) string, will be null padded.
```

These functions are golden when working with other systems that require specific binary protocols, be it zero terminated strings, or ints in a certain "network order" or similar (high versus low endian).